# docker and profile pictures

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2

I have a node app that allows people to upload their profile picture. Profile pictures are stored on the file system.
I now what to turn my node app into a docker container.
I would like to be able to deploy it pretty much anywhere (Amazon, etc.) and realise that storing files within the file system is a no-go.
So:

- Option 1: store files on Amazon's S3 (or something equivalent)
- Option 2: [creating a "data volume](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-docker-data-volumes-on-ubuntu-14-04). This makes me wonder: if I deploy this remotely, will this work? Would this be a long-term way to go about it?

Are [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag) what I want to do here? Is [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-ami-storage-config.html) how you use docker volumes in Amazon?

*(Damn this stuff is hard to crack...)*

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: that depends hehehe

Option 1 is good, resilient, and works just "out-of-the-box", but creates a vendor lock-in. Meaning that if you ever decide to stop using AWS, you'll have some code to refactor. Plus bills for S3 will be high if you perform lots and LOTs of requests.

Option 2 works partially: your docker containers will likely run on VMs on AWS, Azure, etc. which are also ephemeral. Meaning your data can disappear just as quick as if they were on containers, unless you backup them.

Other options I know:

Option 3: AWS have a NFS service (sorry, can't remember its name right now), which seems VERY interesting. In theory, it would be like plugging an USB drive storage to VM instances, which can be mounted as volumes inside the containers. I have never done this myself, but seems viable to reduce S3 costs. However this also generates vendor lock-in.

Option 4: AWS S3 with a caching mechanism for files in the VMs.

If you are just testing, option 1 sounds good! But later on you might have to work on that.